# IntelliSense support for editing NuGet specifications in Visual Studio

Tags: xsd, nuget, intellisense, nuspec

Is there a way for Visual Studio to provide IntelliSense support for NuGet specifications (`*.nuspec`) in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio needs an XML schema available to provide IntelliSense while editing XML files. I created a `nuspec.xsd` schema *specifically for IntelliSense use* by augmenting the schema found in NuGet's source code with documentation annotations.

To use this file:

1. Download the file to your Visual Studio XML schemas folder. For example:

   - Visual Studio 2010: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas`
   - Visual Studio 2012: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas`
2. Make sure to specify the XML namespace in your `.nuspec` file. If you previously used `<package>`, change it to `<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">`

The schema itself may be downloaded from GitHub Gist:
https://gist.github.com/sharwell/6131243

Answer (score 1):

There's a NuGet package for that:

> Install-Package NuSpec

More info on how it's used: http://xavierdecoster.com/post/2012/04/27/install-package-nuspec-aspx

Comment: This package automates the installation, but the schema it uses does not include the schema documentation for elements and attributes. Perhaps it could be updated to use the schema I developed separately?

Comment: it also injects the XSD, so you have intellisense in Visual Studio automatically (if you already created the nuspec upfront, then add the xmlns in the root element)

Comment: or are you talking about a richer XSD you developed? if so, I'm really interested to learn about that! Feel free to submit a PR at https://github.com/myget/nugetpackages

Comment: @XavierDecoster: I believe he's talking about https://gist.github.com/sharwell/6131243, where he has a version of nuspec.xsd that includes documentation for intellisense to display.  Or you could just read [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17995641/294313)...

Comment: The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore. See https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuSpec